# Creating Images from an Embedded Resource

Tags: c#, wpf, embedded-resource

This has been driving me crazy for the past 2 days, and anything close that I find just does not seem to work in my situation, perhaps someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

I have a WPF project to which I've include a fairly large number of images(80ish). I've added them to the project into a folder called "Images". They are currently set to be embedded resources(though I've tried regular resources as well) but nothing seems to work.

I am attempting to create and load an ArrayList of type Image using these files as the source, but I'm failing pretty bad.

```
private void addPicture(string name)
{            
    string filePath = "pack://MyApp_WPF:,,,/Images/" + name + ".png";
    Stream imageStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(filePath);

    Image curImage = new Image();
    BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
    bmpImage.BeginInit();
    bmpImage.UriSource = new Uri(filePath, UriKind.Relative);
    bmpImage.EndInit();
    curImage.Height = 60;
    curImage.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
    curImage.Source = bmpImage;
    curImage.Margin = new Thickness(5);

    imageList.Add(curImage);
}
```

It was much easier to do in my windows form application, but I just cant figure it out with WPF... Any help besides links to resources would be nice, because chances are at this point I've already read them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing to note is that there is an [`DownloadError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.downloadfailed.aspx) event that you ought to subscribe to, this might explain what is happening and why (though sometimes the error message is rather generic); the next is that you might not need the `pack://` URI construct with images build actions of `Resource`:

```
var bmpImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(
    string.Format("/Images/{0}.png", name", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this, tried it again and it worked this time, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) is wrong, where you name your assembly you should place an authority, in this case `application`, i.e.

```
string filePath = "pack://application:,,,/Images/" + name + ".png";
```

Comment: I went ahead and changed it after re-reading about the authority with regards to Pack URI, but for some reason I was getting a parse error with no specifics, so I something else may be wrong. I did end up getting it though!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Somehow including the assembly name works even though the code is in the same assembly: "pack://application:,,,/MyAssemblyName;component/Resources/images/photo.png"