# Load image from resource and apply to Image.source

Tags: c#, wpf, image, resources

I'm using

```
BitmapImage  sharerimg;
sharerimg = new BitmapImage(new Uri("F:/workspace/wpf/NetworkMFServer/NetworkMFServer/imageresources/sharer.png"));
Image im = new Image();
im.Source = sharerimg;
```

But i add image to resources and code this

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string strBaseName = assembly.GetName().Name + ".Properties.Resources";
            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(strBaseName, assembly);
Image im = new Image();
im=(Image)rm.GetObject("sharer");
```

However this show error

> " Can not cast 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Image'"

How can i use image resouce to apply System.Windows.Controls.Image .Source property?

Comment: My image variable 'im' is System.windows.controls.image type and resource image file 'Resources.sharer' is System.Drawing.Bitmap type.  What is fast way using this resource to im

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22957974/1136211).

Comment: clientimg = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/client.png"));  ...And 'resources/client.png' There is no resource

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting BitmapImage to Bitmap and vice versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484357/converting-bitmapimage-to-bitmap-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per MSDN exmaple you should do like this -

```
Image myImage3 = new Image();
BitmapImage bi3 = new BitmapImage();
bi3.BeginInit();
bi3.UriSource = new Uri("smiley_stackpanel.PNG", UriKind.Relative);
bi3.EndInit();
myImage3.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
myImage3.Source = bi3;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source(v=vs.110).aspx

[Accessing embedded image and creating a System.Windows.Controls.Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243351/accessing-embedded-image-and-creating-a-system-windows-controls-image)

Comment: Is it use resource? Is 'smiley_stackpanel.PNG' not local file?

Comment: For resource added SO link . Please check second link

Comment: You mean to say if you try that code asm.GetManifestResourceStream("path.to.resource"); you are getting empty stream?

Comment: Yes.. I correctly add image file to my project resouces

Comment: Please note that you can avoid the BeginInit/EndInit sequence when you use the BitmapImage constructor with Uri parameter (as used in the question): `var bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(...));`

Comment: @LightStar- You used GetCallingAssembly or GetExecutingAssembly function?

Comment: Also note - The GetManifestResourceStream method will always returns NULL if the resource ’built action’ property is not set to ’embedded resource’.